# Update statement in mysql not working, while it has to work

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a problem with an update statement in Mysql. Here is my statement:

```
update `momtos_kullanici` set `firma_quantity`='1', `auditor_quantity`='1', `print_word`=0, `print_excel`=0 WHERE `MK_ID`='2690'
```

This code is executed through PHP and it is not changing the values. I echod it and copied it to phpmyadmin panel and still it is returning '0 rows affected' message, but if I retype the 0 and 1 in `print_word` and `print_excel` columns values in phpmyadmin, it works.

```
Column           Type     null   default

auditor_quantity int(11)  No    1

firma_quantity   int(11)  No    1

print_word       bit(1)   No    0

print_excel      bit(1)   No    0
```

I tried to put number in quotes and even true and false words, the same thing.
I faced with the same problem with varchar field before. In that time, i just said 'oh well...', but this one is really nuts.

Can any one help me? Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Try typing column name without grave character (`). I know it shouldn't be a difference but I just did a test and update did not work unless I did not quoted table name.

Comment: Mysql return 0 in case if any column is not updated though row match.In above case all value you are updating and exciting value in DB are same.

Comment: Thank you guys, I found a workaround solution. converted the bit into int(1) and second thing that i learnt is that update will not change values if stored values are the same as the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Do not enclose your attribute names with quotes

Answer (score 0):

```
update momtos_kullanici set firma_quantity=1, auditor_quantity=1, print_word=0, print_excel=0 WHERE MK_ID=2690
```