# Update in MySQL returning "Rows matched: 1 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0"

Tags: mysql

For some reason, when I do an update on a particular table in MySQL, the response is:

"Rows matched: 1 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0"

I can not for the life of me work out why. I can do a select from the database: (I have X'd out the sensitive data - it's just text)

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM outgoings WHERE id=198;
+-----+---------+---------------+------+-----+----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------------------------------+-----------+------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| id  | user_id | outgoing_date | form | bsb | account_number | transfer_number | amount    | recipient                          | client_id | project_id | purpose          | created_at          | updated_at          | received_from | cheque_number | cheque_to | project_id_from | cheque_drawer                   | recipient_purpose | transferrer_purpose | client_id_from |
+-----+---------+---------------+------+-----+----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------------------------------+-----------+------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| 198 |       2 | 2015-03-11    |    3 |     |                |                 | 407481.25 | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX |       162 |        503 | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX | 2015-03-13 17:51:36 | 2015-03-13 17:51:36 |               | 161           |           |            NULL | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX |                   |                     |           NULL |
+-----+---------+---------------+------+-----+----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------------------------------+-----------+------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, the amount column is 407481.25. I then run a simple update query:

```
mysql> UPDATE cl_time.outgoings SET amount=407481.24 WHERE outgoings.id=198;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

The result shows that nothing was updated, despite the fact that I am actually trying to change something. And if I run the select query again, I see the same result:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM outgoings WHERE id=198;
+-----+---------+---------------+------+-----+----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------------------------------+-----------+------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| id  | user_id | outgoing_date | form | bsb | account_number | transfer_number | amount    | recipient                          | client_id | project_id | purpose          | created_at          | updated_at          | received_from | cheque_number | cheque_to | project_id_from | cheque_drawer                   | recipient_purpose | transferrer_purpose | client_id_from |
+-----+---------+---------------+------+-----+----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------------------------------+-----------+------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| 198 |       2 | 2015-03-11    |    3 |     |                |                 | 407481.25 | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX |       162 |        503 | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX | 2015-03-13 17:51:36 | 2015-03-13 17:51:36 |               | 161           |           |            NULL | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX |                   |                     |           NULL |
+-----+---------+---------------+------+-----+----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------------------------------+-----------+------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

For a bit more context, this is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `outgoings` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `outgoing_date` date NOT NULL,
  `form` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bsb` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `account_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `transfer_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `amount` float(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `recipient` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `purpose` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `received_from` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cheque_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cheque_to` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `project_id_from` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cheque_drawer` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `recipient_purpose` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `transferrer_purpose` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `client_id_from` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `outgoings_user_id_index` (`user_id`),
  KEY `outgoings_client_id_index` (`client_id`),
  KEY `outgoings_project_id_index` (`project_id`),
  KEY `outgoings_project_id_from_index` (`project_id_from`),
  KEY `outgoings_client_id_from_index` (`client_id_from`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=228 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

And finally, this table has data inserted and written to it by a PHP application that I wrote, in Laravel. However, the app never runs an update query on this table. All of this used to work fine, until I migrated the app to a new server, and I'm now unable to run my updates.

Oh, any my mysql version is: 5.5.41, running on Ubuntu.

(These questions seem to be asking much the same, however none of the answers there work for me, so I'm asking here with all of my data: [Why would rows match but not be changed with a mysql update statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148980/why-would-rows-match-but-not-be-changed-with-a-mysql-update-statement) and [Update statement in mysql not working, while it has to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309766/update-statement-in-mysql-not-working-while-it-has-to-work))

Comment: try  `UPDATE cl_time.outgoings SET amount=407482.24 WHERE outgoings.id=198;` different amount and see it

Comment: This is an old question, but you really should not use `float()` for a monetary amount because it's not accurate. That's extremely poor design. You should be using something like `numeric(22,2)` or `decimal(22,2)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason an update doesn't change the value of your row is because of rounding issues. You have defined `amount` as `float(8,2)`. You are then changing the value from `407481.25` to `407481.24` - the difference is mere 0.01 between them but we know that computers have rounding issues.

Due to the fact that an update doesn't write the new value, it's 100% safe to conclude that MySQL sees the two numbers as the same due to rounding issues. **If a record isn't really altered, MySQL won't write it down** - this is an optimization step, MySQL won't involve hard drive into work if it doesn't have to.

Now, this means you need to adjust your `amount` column type and change it to either an integer and then internally move the decimal point for two places to the left or use a data type such as `decimal` with larger decimal digits maximum number (for example: `amount DECIMAL(8,4)`).

Comment: You, my good sir, are a genius! Thanks! The only warning I would give to anyone reading this after the fact is that a `DECIMAL(8,4)` field can hold a maximum value of 9999.9999, so something like `DECIMAL(10,4)` or `DECIMAL(12,4)` is necessary to store my values of 400,000+.

Comment: "_**If a record isn't really altered, MySQL won't write it down - this is an optimization step, MySQL won't involved hard drive into work if it doesn't have to.**_". Good to know, I was wondering why the update query is not updating it with the same value already present. Saved my day.

Comment: Is there any work around to force MySQL to update that?

Comment: @Pronoy999 - if you are relying on info that MySQL gives back after update or insert, it might be a good idea to ask about what you're trying to achieve. Someone will definitely have a different approach that doesn't involve making MySQL write data that's already there.

Answer (score 3):

In mysql updates, when the values in the row don't actually change, it doesn't count toward the changed row count (obviously).

"Changed" means "the new values are different from the old values".

Answer (score -1):

you can change the data type to DOUBLE :

```
alter table outgoings modify amount DOUBLE;
```